# How can I control which USB devices that can be used on a computer?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I want to have control over which USB devices can be used on a computer. Perhaps by providing a white list or something similar. Are there any applications for this?

For example, I'd like to only allow an Ethernet adapter device and nothing else.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: What about USB keyboard and mice?

Comment: Good point! In general keyboard and mice devices would be allowed but in my specific case I want to do this on a tablet PC without keyboard and mice.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there does not seem to be a program to do what you are after, but you can completely disable the use of USB storage devices.

From [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-restrict-use-of-usb-storage-devices-in-windows/):

> 1. Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. Now goto:
>
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor`
> 2. In right-side pane, change value of "Start" to 4
> 3. Reset your computer

After doing this you will no longer be able to detect or mount USB storage devices.  If you want to put this back to the way it was then change the value of "Start" back to 3.

You can also use the [Group Policy Editor](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_usb_disks_with_gpo.htm) to disable USB storage devices.